# how to use datetime fields as period range? are there some alternatives?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm writing some fields about some events in my database and I was thinking that I can do with:

```
rangeType (varchar) (may be: daily, weekly, monthly, yearly)
rangeStart (datetime)
rangeEnd (datetime)
```

I want to match a record when `NOW()` is in the range of time:

- when `rangeType` is `'yearly'`, if date of `NOW()` is between the month+days of `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd`
- when `rangeType` is `'monthly'` if `NOW()` is between the days of `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd`
- when `rangeType` is `'weekly'` if `NOW()` is....
- when `rangeType` is `'daily'` if the time of `NOW()` is....

I think weekly needs a special treatment here, and the overall structure is not so flexible...

Then I need more fields! but I want something easy to read and mantain... what is the best way to do this with MySQL? Is there some function that allows me to do this without writing and mantain rows and rows of SQL?

What about the ISO8601 period specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT ...
WHERE CASE rangeType
  WHEN 'daily'   THEN TIME(      NOW()) BETWEEN TIME(      rangeStart) AND TIME(      rangeEnd)
  WHEN 'weekly'  THEN DAYOFWEEK( NOW()) BETWEEN DAYOFWEEK( rangeStart) AND DAYOFWEEK( rangeEnd)
  WHEN 'monthly' THEN DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) BETWEEN DAYOFMONTH(rangeStart) AND DAYOFMONTH(rangeEnd)
  WHEN 'yearly'  THEN DAYOFYEAR( NOW()) BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR( rangeStart) AND DAYOFYEAR( rangeEnd)
END
```

Comment: nice! dayofweek considers the day of the specified year? thanks!

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer: [`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) gives an integer 1 to 7 indicating Sunday to Saturday respectively (but yes, it calculates the day of the week giving consideration to the year).

Comment: SELECT
DAYOFWEEK('2010-10-10') as dow1,
DAYOFWEEK('2012-10-10') AS dow2

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer: I'm not sure that I understand your question; as mentioned in my previous comment, `DAYOFWEEK()` will give consideration to the year - so in your example `dow1` would be `1` (10 Oct 2010 was a Sunday) whilst `dow2` would be `4` (10 Oct 2012 will be a Wednesday).

Comment: was just an example for who is interested in the answer!